# Recursive summation constraint on OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

I want to write a recursive summation function in OPL. 
To summarize in words, for all j (some index), I want to sum a variable over j; but until that j (the upper bound of summation). 
For example suppose j is in 1..5 range. For j=3 I want to sum x1+x2+x3<=A
For j=4 it should be x1+x2+x3+x4<=A

I wrote the below code, but i know it won't work correctly. Any suggestions on this?

```
 forall(i in subjects, j in days)
   sum(j in days) x[i][j]<= i.PageNumber*(1-a[i][j]);
```

Here, what condition can I add in the summation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for

```
 forall(i in subjects, j in days)
   sum(g in 1..j) x[i][g]<= i.PageNumber*(1-a[i][j]);
```